# Align master page and search result HTML

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

In SharePoint 2013:

I have a custom master page where I would like to move the PageTitle to a different .  That's not a problem, but the Search Results page (osssearchresults.aspx) gets its title/menu from somewhere else.  I was able to successfully get my master page style to apply by editing the Display Template 'Control_SearchResults.html', but that doesn't contain the HTML for the title/menu.

You can see below - by default the title comes BEFORE the menu in a master page and the title comes AFTER the menu on the search results HTML.  This slight appearance difference wasn't a problem, but now I want to move the PageTitle somewhere very different.

[image: Same HTML, different order]

Any idea how to change the HTML for the search page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten that there are two different 'master page' settings - the 'master page' and the 'system master page'.  The search results page uses the 'system master page.'  When I changed 'seattle' to my master page below all is well.
[image]